# Listview Searchview for custom adapter not working properly

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, searchview

I am creating an android application. In the application I have a login page. After login a userlist is displayed. The userlist activity is HomeActivity.java that contains two fragments named as UserListFragment.java and ChatFragment.java The userlist is getting displayed from firebase. The UserListFragment.java contains an actionbar which has a search menu and logout menu.

I am using searchview in actionbar and its working okay i.e. its searching the contents.But I have two issues with it.

1) If I search something which is not present. Suppose "Rider" is there in listview, so it will search but if I type "Rids" and the listview doesn't contain any such user with similar letters, so as soon as I type "s" my app crashes.

2) Now, the next issue I am facing is. I have the userlist and when I click on some user it goes to another fragment i.e. ChatFragment. Now if I come back from the ChatFragment back to my UserFragment where my list is displayed, only the user whose name I searched previously, are getting displayed and not my original userlist.

I am posting the code which is relevant to my question. In case you need any other code, please let me know.

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

            if (results != null) {
                clear();
                addAll((List<UserData>) results.values);
                arrayList = (List<UserData>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
            List<UserData> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<UserData>();

            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<UserData>(arrayList); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
            }

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                // set the Original result to return
                results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                results.values = mOriginalValues;
            } else {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
               // Log.i(TAG,mOriginalValues.toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                    String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).getName();
                    //String temp = mOriginalValues.add()
                    if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                        FilteredArrList.add(mOriginalValues.get(i));
                        results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                        results.values = FilteredArrList;
                    }
                }
                // set the Filtered result to return

            }

            return results;
        }

    };
    return filter;
}
```

**UserListFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_userlist,menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Log.i(TAG,newText);
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
    SearchView.OnCloseListener closeListener = new SearchView.OnCloseListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            adapter.getFilter().filter("");
            return true;
        }
    };
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}

private void logoutUser(){
    Intent I = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(I);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuSearch :
            return true;

        case R.id.menuLogout :
            logoutUser();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**Log**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: , PID: 21743
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference
                  at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:188)
                  at     android.widget.ArrayAdapter.addAll(ArrayAdapter.java:195)
                  at CustomAdapter$1.publishResults(CustomAdapter.java:135)
                  at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
D/Surface: Surface::setBuffersDimensions(this=0x7f8ea1b400,w=720,h=1280)
```

Comment: regarding issue 1, what error r u getting. pls post ur stack trace

Comment: @darwin added stack trace.

Comment: i think the issue is with addAll((List<UserData>) results.values);, may be result.values is null.make sure that result.values is not null

Comment: Can you help me with what can I do to resolve it.? I can tell you what I want to do if the user with name is not present. I want to print a statement no search results in my listview as it generally happens in the applications, if you have no results.

Comment: use ''if(results.values !=null)'' instead  ''if(results !=null)'' and check that crash still occurs or not

Comment: @darwin Thanks a lot. :) The app didn't crash now.
Do you have any idea for my second issue.

Comment: may be u have set back stack to true on replacing fragment,or u can use ur own logic to load all data on coming back to userlist fragment

Comment: And also I have one issue. If there's no item matching user's search then I want to display **No results** how can I do that.?

Comment: u can add a text view xml file above the list view and change the visibilty on that view depends on the result.u canuse an interface or event bus for communication between activity and the adaptor

Comment: @darwin Thank you so so much. Will try your solution. :)